# Using Case When in the Where Clause in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, where-clause, case-when

I have a procedure which has an input parameter p_card_type. Based on the input parameter, the where clause changes. Here is a what the query looks like. I have 4 different options and they all error out.

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE CARD_TYPE in (p_card_type)
```

--Here are the 4 options I have tried.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE   
- Case p_card_type when 'EGC/VEGC' THEN CARD_TYPE in ('EGC', 'VEGC') else CARD_TYPE in (p_card_type) End

- Case WHEN p_card_type = 'EGC/VEGC' THEN CARD_TYPE in ('EGC', 'VEGC') else CARD_TYPE in (p_card_type) End

- CARD_TYPE in Case WHEN p_card_type = 'EGC/VEGC' THEN ('EGC', 'VEGC') else (p_card_type) End

- CARD_TYPE in Case p_card_type WHEN 'EGC/VEGC' THEN ('EGC', 'VEGC') else (p_card_type) End
```

The error I get is 
ORA-06550: PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06550: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Would really appreciate any kind of help on this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your query with some boolean logic, in a more readable way:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE   
     ( p_card_type ='EGC/VEGC' AND CARD_TYPE in ('EGC', 'VEGC') )
     OR
     ( ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most index-friendly solution:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   p_card_type = 'EGC/VEGC'
        AND card_type IN ('EGC', 'VEGC')
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   p_card_type <> 'EGC/VEGC'
        AND card_type = p_card_type
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both the solutions work. Will look at the execution time for the best fit.

Comment: The union seems unnecessary - why scan the base table twice when it can be done in one pass? Just combine the where clauses with the OR operator.

Comment: @mathguy: Oracle's optimizer is smart enough as not to scan the table if the condition on `p_card_type` (the input parameter) is invalid.